# How to make quarto use the same python environment that was specified in RStudio global options?

Tags: python, rstudio, quarto

I have a virtual environment python interpreter selected in RStudio as shown here:

[image]

But when I use a `python` chunk in quarto, I see that the base environment is being used (the output was rendered by quarto):

````
```{python}
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```
C:/Users/USERNAME/anaconda3/python.exe
````

How can I make quarto use the `homl3` environment as specified in RStudio global options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also struggling to be able to control which version of Python I am using in RStudio and Quarto.

I found a solution that works for me, which does not exactly answer your specific question, but maybe it works for you too:

I control the Python version via the reticulate package ([Link to package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=reticulate)). Python can be installed e.g. via `reticulate::install_miniconda()`.

You can then create even several virtual environments that can be activated in RStudio and also when compiling a quarto document:

```
reticulate::virtualenv_create('my-environment')
```

In the RStudio console and also in your quarto document you can activate the environment you want to work with, e.g.:

```
reticulate::use_virtualenv('my-environment')
```

In this environment you can install the python packages you need with the reticulate package:

```
reticulate::conda_install('my-environment', 'pandas')
```

Maybe this helps? Further information can be found in the package vignettes of the reticulate package.

Comment: Thanks! I also figured out the `reticulate::use_virtualenv('my-environment')` workaround in quarto. Strangely, this wasn't an issue in a previous version of RStudio.